# Java script doesnt work

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I am trying to learn javascript and I found an example but icant make it run What am i doing wrong

```
 function CheckForPastDate(sender, args) {

        selectedDate = sender._selectedDate;
        var todayDate = new Date();
        if (selectedDate.getDateOnly() < todayDate.getDateOnly()) {
            sender.selectedDate = todayDate;
            sender._textbox.set_Value(sender.selectedDate.format(sender._format));
            alert("Wrong date!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where and how do you want to run it? i mean from where you are calling `CheckForPastDate()`?

Comment: `"I can't make it run"` isn't a very meaningful problem description.  In what way does the code fail?  Is there an error on the JavaScript console?  Is the code not doing what you expect?  When you step through the code in a debugger, at what point does the observed behavior differ from the expected behavior?

Comment: You can share a fiddle to get more help.

Comment: @Kuzgun Fiddles should be supplementary. The post should contain all the needed markup to reproduce and explain the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made couple of mistakes in your code assuming that the code written is in javascript

Date comparisons need to be like this

```js
if (selectedDate.getTime() < todayDate.getTime()) {
```

And you cannot format the dates in Javascript.
You can use the API available if you want.
Like the one I used [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/)

```js
sender._textbox.value = moment(sender.selectedDate).format(sender._format);
```

See my sample: http://jsfiddle.net/vinodgubbala/6MEG6/

Comment: Hi, I was fallowing this tutorial .And İt works there .I am very confused

Comment: Whats confusing? I just used JS in the rightways. I pointed the changes i did in the highlights above